# LibGdx game dev shooting bullets

Tags: libgdx, box2d

So basically every time i shoot, a new dynamic body is created with linear impulse , after constantly shooting my bullets game starts to get slow( it's obvious because i constantly create a new object..). What should i do to avoid this problem, i tried deleting objects, bodies?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Too broad question. Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still new to Java, but the way I understand it is that if anything references an object, that object won't be picked up by the recycler. Triple check all of your arrays and lists to make sure one isn't filling up with bullets. Display the sizes of your arrays while playing to see if one is acting weird.

For each bullet you probably want to see if it is off screen. If so, remove it from the list/array.

Comment: Thanks you answer helped me a lot, i debuged my game better and i found the problem :).

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late but for future readers, Libgdx has something called object pooling specifically meant for things like this.